# Multiple Vnets and subnets using terraform modules

Tags: terraform

I am new to terraform and I am trying to create module for multiple vnets and under that multiple subnets

I am able to create multiple vnets using the module but I am facing issue in creating multiple subnets on one or more of the vnets created.

Below is my code for the module and as well as main.tf

**network resources module/main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "network" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnets" {
  count               = length(var.vnet_names)
  name                = var.vnet_names[count.index]
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  location            = var.vnet_location != null ? var.vnet_location : data.azurerm_resource_group.network.location
  address_space       = [var.vnet_adress_spaces[count.index]]
}
```

**network resources module/variables.tf**

```
variable "vnet_names" {
  description = "Name of the vnets to be created"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["vnet1","vnet2","vnet3"]
}

variable "vnet_adress_spaces" {
  description = "Name of the vnets to be created"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["192.168.0.0/16" ,"10.0.0.0/16","10.80.0.0/16"]
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the resource group to be imported."
  type        = string
}

variable "vnet_location" {
  description = "The location of the vnet to create. Defaults to the location of the resource group."
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

variable "subnet_names" {
  description = "The list of subnets which needs to be created"
  type        = list(list(string))
  default     = [[],["subnet1_vnet1","subnet2_vnet1"],["subnet1_vnet3","subnet2_vnet3","subnet3_vnet3"]]
}

variable "subnet_addresses" {
  description = "The list of subnets which needs to be created"
  type        = list(list(string))
  default     = [[],["10.0.2.0/24","10.0.0.0/24"],["10.80.2.0/24","10.80.1.0/24","10.80.0.0/24"]]
}
```

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.98.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg1" {
  name     = "rg1"
  location = "West Europe"
}

module network {
  source              = "./network_resources"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
}
```

3 vnets are successfully created but I am facing issue in writing subnet creation as mentioned in variables.tf
Please can you help me with that or suggest a better way of implementing this

**Output.tf of module**

```
output "vnet_names" {
  description = "The name of the virtual networks"
  value       = {for k, v in azurerm_virtual_network.vnets: k => v.name}
} 

output "vnet_addresses" {
  description = "The name of the virtual networks"
  value       = {for k, v in azurerm_virtual_network.vnets: k => v.address_space}
} 

output "subnet_names" {
  description = "The name of the subnets"
  value       = {for k, v in azurerm_subnet.subnets: k => v.name}
} 

output "subnet_addresses" {
  description = "The name of the subnet addresses"
  value       = {for k, v in azurerm_subnet.subnets: k => v.address_prefixes}
} 

output "subnet_ids" {
  description = "The name of the subnet addresses"
  value       = {for k, v in azurerm_subnet.subnets: k => v.id}
}
```

When I am taking the subnet value same for two vnets as per the updated variables.tf

```
vnets = {
    "mel-dev-identity-vnet01" = {
      address_space = "10.0.0.0/16",
      subnets = [
        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet-mel-AD-dev"
          subnet_address = "10.0.2.0/24"
          service_endpoints = []
        },
        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet-mel-okt-dev"
          subnet_address = "10.0.0.0/24"
          service_endpoints = []
          
        },
        {
          subnet_name    = "GatewaySubnet"
          subnet_address = "10.0.0.0/26"
          service_endpoints = []
          
        },
      ]
    },

    "mel-dev-identity-vnet02" = {
      address_space = "10.80.0.0/16"
      subnets = [
        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet-syd-AD-dev"
          subnet_address = "10.80.2.0/24"
          service_endpoints = []
          
        },

        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet-syd-okt-dev"
          subnet_address = "10.80.1.0/24"
          service_endpoints = []
          
        },

        {
          subnet_name    = "GatewaySubnet"
          subnet_address = "10.80.0.0/26"
          service_endpoints = []
         
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

I am getting the below error:

│ Error: Duplicate object key
│
│   on network_resources\locals.tf line 11, in locals:
│   11:   subnets = { for subnet in local.subnets_flatlist : subnet.subnet_name => subnet }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ subnet.subnet_name is "GatewaySubnet"
│
│ Two different items produced the key "GatewaySubnet" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the
│ ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.

Comment: You could try using `cidrsubnets`: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/cidrsubnets.

Comment: In your outputs you are spreading attributs of resources across multiple maps. I would prefer returning two maps of the create resources
`output "subnets" { value = azurerm_subnet.subnets }`and `output "vnets" { value = azurerm_virtual_network.vnets }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues in your code:

1. You store attributes (e.g. subnet_name, subnet_addressed) of the same resources in different variables of type list or nested list.
   This way you have to ensure consistency across the different variables manually which can become tedious and error prone. Imagine you want to add a third subnet to vnet *bupavnet2*. You have to make sure that you insert the new name and subnet at the corresponding positions in two nested lists.

   BTW: Is it intended that the subnets in vnet *bupavnet**2*** are named *subnet#-bupavnet**1*** ? See what I mean ??? :)
2. In order to create multiple subnets in multiple vnets dynamically, you would need a nested loop which iterates over the vnets in the outer loop and across the subnets in the inner loop. Terraform, however, does not support nested for_each loops on resource level.

One way to overcome the first issue is to use complex types like objects or maps in order to make the relationship between the attributes of a resource explicit. This way it would be easy to spot the naming issue of the subnets in *bupavnet**2***. If you want to add an additional subnet, you just need to add an additional object to the subnets list.

```
variable "vnets" {
  type = map(object({
    address_space = string
    subnets = list(object({
      subnet_name    = string
      subnet_address = string
    }))
  }))

  default = {
    "bupavnet1" = {
      address_space = "192.168.0.0/16",
      subnets       = []
    },
    "bupavnet2" = {
      address_space = "10.0.0.0/16",
      subnets = [
        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet1_bupavnet1"
          subnet_address = "10.0.2.0/24"
        },
        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet2_bupavnet1"
          subnet_address = "10.0.0.0/24"
        }
      ]
    },

    "bupavnet3" = {
      address_space = "10.80.0.0/16"
      subnets = [
        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet1_bupavnet3"
          subnet_address = "10.80.2.0/24"
        },

        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet2_bupavnet3"
          subnet_address = "10.80.1.0/24"
        },

        {
          subnet_name    = "subnet3_bupavnet3"
          subnet_address = "10.80.0.0/24"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In succession, the creation of the vnets would change to

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnets" {
  for_each            = var.vnets
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  location            = var.vnet_location != null ? var.vnet_location : data.azurerm_resource_group.network.location
  address_space       = [each.value.address_space]
}
```

Now let's have a look how to tackle the *nested for loop issue*. In Terraform you would address this by flattening the nested structure which we defined above. In the first step we create a flat list of objects representing the subnets to be created. So our variable `subnets_flatlist` has the type *tuple of objects*.
Unfortunately the `for_each` argument in Terraform requires the type *map* or *set of strings*. So we need a second step to create a map out of our flat list.

```
locals {
  subnets_flatlist = flatten([for key, val in var.vnets : [
    for subnet in val.subnets : {
      vnet_name      = key
      subnet_name    = subnet.subnet_name
      subnet_address = subnet.subnet_address
    }
    ]
  ])

  subnets = { for subnet in local.subnets_flatlist : subnet.subnet_name => subnet }
}
```

Once we created our helper structures we can iterate over the subnets map and create the subnet resources:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each             = local.subnets
  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.network.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnets[each.value.vnet_name].name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.subnet_address]
}
```

Comment: it worked fine. I have to convert this to module which I have already done. The issue what I am facing right now is how to reference only one subnet as input to another module . I have added the output of the module in my question. I have a nsg module which will be used for creating nsg and attaching the nsg to subnet for which I need to get subnets individually so that they can be used in nsg module

Comment: Assuming that you would like to reference `subnet2_bupavnet1` in the nsg creation, you would need to use `module.yourmodulename.subnet_ids["subnet2_bupavnet1"]` when referencing form your main module or
`azurerm_subnet.subnets["subnet2_bupavnet1"].id` from within the submodule which creates the subnets.

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working but we are hardcoding the values here. Is there any other way to not hardcode values and achieve it

Comment: @Aniket I agree that this is not desirable, but as I understood you only want to assign the nsg to one of the subnets. So you have to id the subnet somehow. What would you prefer as an identifier?

Another solution I could imagine is to add an identifier to the subnet object in the *vnets* map variable. If you add an additional attribute like `enable_nsg = bool`, you could iterate over the structure to find all subnets which should get the nsg assigned (which could then be more than one).

Comment: if we add enable_nsg = bool , then we need to define the nsg also inside the network_resources module. please correct me if I am wrong and I also wanted to know the way in which output of the module can be used in any another module and how it can be iterated

Comment: Another query which I needed to ask was if I am adding `service_endpoints = list(string)` as part of subnet in variables, then how will the helper structure change to accomodate service_endpoints as this will be a list of string .

Comment: @Aniket's comment 3: True, but instead of defining the structure in the variable definition as default, you could define it in the calling module as `local` and then pass it to two submodules (which is kind of ugly).

Comment: @Aniket's comment 4: This is lacking a bit of information on what you want to achieve and it is quite moving away from the initial question. In order to keep this conversation readable, would you mind providing the state you reached now and what you want to achieve in the next step as a new question?

Comment: thanks for all the help @stdtom. I will ask the above issue as a new question.

Comment: i am facing an issue when i have subnets with the same name under the two vnets. i have done the changes in the variables part in your answer│ Error: Duplicate object key
│
│   on network_resources\locals.tf line 11, in locals:
│   11:   subnets = { for subnet in local.subnets_flatlist : subnet.subnet_name => subnet }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ subnet.subnet_name is "GatewaySubnet"
│
│ Two different items produced the key "GatewaySubnet" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the       
│ ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key..

Comment: I have made edits in question. please can you check on the error